# Why does Node.js session storage have such an impact on performance?

Tags: node.js, express

With the following enabled:

```
  app.use(express.session({
    store: sessionStore,
    secret: 'secret',
    key: 'express.sid'}));
```

Whilst testing my Node.js application the throughput of requests is **650 Requests per second.**

When I don't use `express.session`, the throughput of requests is **2200 Requests per second.**

Testing with apache bench with the following parameters: 
`-k -c 256 -n 50000 http://localhost:3000/`.

I'm testing against the following:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res)
{
  res.redirect('/login');  
});
```

**Question: Is this a normal drop in performance, or is there something which I should be looking at fixing?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say, it is "normal". I don't have any benchmarks myself to compare to yours, but since you are creating session ID from crypto, as well as looking up in your storage (which I hope is memcache or redis or some key/value store), such a drop seems natural. Without session, you are doing absolutely nothing and not waiting for any IO either..

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know what was going on behind the scenes in that much detail.

Comment: maybe someone else has more insight. Also -> you may want to increase the concurrent connections in the benchmark to see how node.js can handle ALOT of concurrent connections.

Comment: It's just Windows 7 which is really slow! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243221/does-node-js-perform-badly-on-windows-surely-it-cant-be-slower-than-apache-for

Btw i'm working in Linux now the same application is capable of dealing with 3500 req / sec. I'm now also implementing clustering and a quick bench showed 18000 req / sec. I'm having problems with Socket.io though :(!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245044/socket-io-websocket-authorization-failing-when-clustering-node-application