# FastAPI responding slowly when calling through other Python app, but fast in cURL

Tags: python, windows, python-requests, fastapi, asgi

I have an issue that I can't wrap my head around. I have an API service built using FastAPI, and when I try to call any endpoint from another Python script on my local machine, the response takes 2+ seconds. When I send the same request through cURL or the built-in Swagger docs, the response is nearly instant.

The entire server script is this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

I then call it from a test script using HTTPX. I also tried with the requests package, and it is the same result.

```
import httpx
r = httpx.get('http://localhost:8000/')
print(r.elapsed)
```

This prints something like: `0:00:02.069705`

I then do the same thing using cURL:

```
curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000/'
```

This prints:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    32  100    32    0     0    941      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   969
     time_namelookup:  0.006436s
        time_connect:  0.006747s
     time_appconnect:  0.000000s
    time_pretransfer:  0.006788s
       time_redirect:  0.000000s
  time_starttransfer:  0.034037s
                     ----------
          time_total:  0.034093s
```

The issue isn't what the endpoint does, but rather that it doesn't even start executing for 2 seconds. I have a debugger running on the endpoint, and the first line only gets executed after those 2 seconds.

I tried to inspect the request to see whether there are any headers or similar in the request that could slow it down, but nothing. When I try again with the headers generated by HTTPX, it still executes fast:

```
curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8000/events' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'host: localhost:8000' \
  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'user-agent: python-httpx/0.20.0'
```

Here is a screenshot of the request in PyCharm, it unfortunately can't be dumped to JSON directly.
[image]

I'm starting to think that it has something to do with Uvicorn and how it runs the app, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: I have no solution to offer, but have to tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost? I once had a similar issues where it would take half a second or more for my windows machine to resolve the host name before it would make the actual request.

Comment: Well the python itself might be bottleneck. Could you try to debug the request on the client site? Could be problem with HTTP/1 vs HTTP/2

Comment: @thisisalsomypassword Oh god you are right. Switching to 127.0.0.1 literally solves it. I can not thank you enough, I already spent multiple hours on this. This really should not happen though.

Comment: I was kind of afraid to suggest it but it reminded me too much of my issue. I was making the request from javascript in the browser, though. It didn‘t bother to look into it any further then, so sorry I don‘t have a solution. But maybe it narrows down your search.

Comment: Oh you definitely solved my issue. That was exactly the problem.

Comment: Well, glad it helped.

Comment: Why not put that 127.0.0.1 as answer though you may also want to tag question as  `windows`?  @thisisalsomypassword. Easier to find solution as answer than comment, later.

Comment: Yes, you‘re right. Will do.

Comment: You're right. I added the Windows tag to the post.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using „127.0.0.1“ instead of „localhost“ to refer to your machine. I once had a similar issue, where the DNS lookup for localhost on windows was taking half a second or longer. I don‘t have an explanation for that behaviour, but at least [one other person](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9244784/14412190) on SO seems to have struggled with it as well…